# Add partial month to Month total in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

In order to complete some calculations in my table, I need to take all months between a start and end dates.  However, for the calculation to work properly, I need to be able to include a portion of the start month.

Here is an example of what I am currently doing.  This will give me the count of months between the start and end date.

```
DepreciationPeriods -  DateDiff(Month, AcquisitionDate, @STARTDATE)  END as RemainingPeriodAsOfStartDate
```

However, the AcquisitionDate is not always taking place on the 1st of the month.  Therefore, if the Acquistiondate is on the 15th of June and the end date is August 1st.  I want the result to be 1.5 months and not 2 months like the code is currently giving

I have tried the following line:

```
 DepreciationPeriods -  DateDiff(Month, AcquisitionDate, @STARTDATE) + cast(EOMONTH(acquisitiondate as int) / cast( day(AcquisitionDate as int)) -1)
```

However, I am still receiving error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 10, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: This doesn't make sense:  `EOMONTH(acquisitiondate as int)`.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the calculation would make it possible for other people to help you.

Comment: cast(day(EOMONTH(acquisitiondate)) as int) / cast( day(AcquisitionDate) as int).

Answer (score 0):

You need to appreciate that DATEDIFF does not count then number of intervals between two date, it counts the number of times the specified interval changes between two dates. As an extreme example if you ask DATEDIFF to tell you the number of years between `'1999-12-31 23:59:59'` and `'2000-01-01 00:00:01'` it will say they are a year apart (1 year different) even though they are only two seconds apart, because the year changed once (1999->2000) between the two dates

As such, because you want some fractional element of "number of intervals" between two dates you'll have to use a finer grained interval, like days (if you want number-of-months) or seconds (if you want number-of-minutes), between your dates and then divide that interval (150 minutes between two dates, divided by 60.0 gives 2.5 hours to get an approximation (you have to accept that a time of `00:00:00 - 02:30:59` is nearly two whole minutes longer than `00:00:59 - 02:30:00` but the minutes interval still changed the same number of times) of the whole.

In this particular case it's troublesome because months vary in length, so even if you have two dates that are eg the 1st of one month and the 15th of another, they aren't always going to be 1.5 months apart because the 15th isn't always half a month (15/28 vs 15/31)

If you can tolerate this, then use eg days in your datediff and something like the average number of days in a month

If you cannot tolerate it, perhaps get the length of the month (`DAY(EOMOTH(date))`) that your "half month" falls in, be it the start date or the end date, and calculate what day in that month equates to "half a month" (i.e. between 28/2 and 31/2)